# How to add inner-shadow on image React-Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styles, react-native-stylesheet

How can i apply buttom inner shadow like this image in react native?
[Buttom inner shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4y3C.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think you refer to a radial-gradient applied on the background of the element.

```
Button {
background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), black);
}
```

There are options to manipulate the same gradient with % porcentages in order to get a thiner effect or thicker effect

Comment: Hi Jose,
it's a little bit complicated for me. my code is like this
```<View style={styles.container}>
   <Image style={styles.image} source=.../>
</View>```
the problem is the Image cover my View so i cant cover the background gradient to it. how is it possible to give my View Cointainer this style?

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I cant add comments so i am going with another idea. BUT this wont work if you have to click.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
 }

.container::after {
  Position:absolute;
  Inset:0;
  Content:'';
  Background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), black);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This trick will make a cover box that can add a filter style. But if you have to click something, we need to go further than this.